Promise all is blocking other fetch call
I actually consume some remote API using the FETCH API like below
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    loadCart();
    aggregateSearch("france", ["api1", "api2"]);
});

const aggregateSearch = async (term, AvailableApis) => {
    console.log("aggregateSearch")
    await Promise.all(AvailableApis.map((api) => {
        fetchApi(api, term);
    }))
};

const fetchApi = async (api, term) => {
    console.log("fetchApi");
    const aggregateRawResponse = await fetch('aggregate.php', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({ source: api, term: term }) });
    const aggregateResponse = await aggregateRawResponse.json();

    console.log('response from API done');

    document.getElementById('myDiv' + api)?.innerHTML = aggregateResponse.formattedResponse;
}

const updateCartCount = async () => {
    console.log("update cartcount"); // this line is executed
    const fetchNbPhotos = await fetch("count.php");
    const data = await fetchNbPhotos.json();
    console.log("cart count done");
    document.getElementById('cartCounter').innerHTML = parseInt(data["nb"]); // this is executed once aggregateSearch done
}

const loadCart = () => {
    console.log("start loading cart");
    fetch('cart.php')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((html) => {
        console.log("loading cart is done updating cart count");
        document.getElementById('cart')?.innerHTML = html
        updateCartCount();
    });
}

Here the console output
start loading cart
aggregateSearch
fetchApi
loading cart is done updating cart count
update cartcount
cart count done
response from API done

The part that retrieves the contents of the APIs works perfectly, but the part that load my cart into cart div and updating my cartCounter div is only update once aggregateSearch has finished.
I tried to make loadCart async/await but without success
How can I make aggregateSearch non-blocking and update my cartCounter div while fetching API is pending ?
EDIT
I tried to change the aggregateSearch like below
const aggregateSearch = async (term, AvailableApis) => {
    console.log("aggregateSearch")
    await Promise.all(AvailableApis.map((api) => {
        setTimeout(() => fetchApi(api, fulltext, []), 100);
        //fetchApi(api, fulltext, []);
    }))
};

And my cartCounter div id updated instantly
EDIT2
Here is the reproductible example https://jsfiddle.net/3sdLweag/26/
Console output
"start loading cart"
"aggregateSearch"
"update cartcount"
"response from API done"
"cart count done"

As fetchApi has 2000 delay, loadCart and updateCartCount have 100 delay both expected output should be
"start loading cart"
"aggregateSearch"
"update cartcount"
"cart count done"
"response from API done"


await Promise.all(AvailableApis.map((api) => { fetchApi(api, term); })) doesn't wait for the promises, since there are no promises made from that call. Just an array of undefined which will be resolved immediately. Either add return or remove the curly brackets

array of undefined ? fetchApi is async, console.log(fetchApi(api, term)) returns Promise {<pending>}

An arrow function with curly braces needs an explicit return statement to return something. (api) => { fetchApi(api, term); } returns undefined, not the expected promise. Either remove the braces (api) => fetchApi(api, term) or add a return statement (api) => { return fetchApi(api, term); }

@akio (api) => { fetchApi(api, term); } is a function that only returns undefined Why is my arrow function with a braced body returning undefined? | When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions

So, in summary - I have no idea what the problem is because what you describe is impossible. aggregateSearch shouldn't "block" anything. It should resolve next tick - far before any of the async functions it starts (but doesn't wait for) finishes.

In fact it's not really blocking, but until aggregateSearch is done and document.getElementById('myDiv' + api)?.innerHTML executed, my cartCounter  div content is not updated. If I wrap fetchApi call with 100ms setTimeout it is updated immediatly

Can you provide a [mcve] with mocked fetch function?

The weird things is that with replacing fetch call with setTimeout instead it works .. there is an another way to mock fetch without dependencies?

There are several issues with your code, but I don't understand why you say "updating my cartCounter div is only update once aggregateSearch has finished", because from the output you have given, we see that the HTML is updated in this order: cart, then cartCounter and then myDiv+api. That seems to be the order you want? What is the order of the output you expected?

In my app cart count done and response from API done being executed at same time, so all html element are populated simultaneously not once fetch is done

All your requests are independent from each other, so there is no guaranteed order for their completion and the DOM updates. (And it sounds like you don't want one?). However, they're still all requests to the same server/domain, and your browser may be throttling that to allow only a modest number of concurrent connections per domain. For that reason, the request (cartcount) that started last may have to wait until it's actually being sent until the previous requests have finished.

It looks like you want loadCart to finish its asychronous parts -- ending with an update of the cartCounter -- before the aggregateSearch fetch is initiated, as that is what your setTimeout version will likely achieve.
Then the solution is to await the asynchronous tasks made by loadCart.
First of all loadCart should return a promise. It needs a return at two spots in your code
const loadCart = () => {
    console.log("start loading cart");
    return fetch('cart.php')  // <-- return the promise!
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((html) => {
        console.log("loading cart is done updating cart count");
        document.getElementById('cart')?.innerHTML = html;
        return updateCartCount(); // <-- return the promise!
    });
}

Or, alternatively, write that function as an async function, just like you did at other places in your code:
const loadCart = async () => { // <-- make it async
    console.log("start loading cart");
    const response = await fetch('cart.php');  // <-- and use await
    const html = await response.text();        // <-- 
    console.log("loading cart is done updating cart count");
    document.getElementById('cart')?.innerHTML = html;
    return updateCartCount(); // <-- return the promise!
}

Another point is that you don't get a useful result from Promise.all, as you don't pass it an array of promises. This makes the await operator on that Promise.all quite useless. It has no negative effect in your case, as you never use that result, but it would make more sense to do it in the right way, and have aggregateSearch return a promise that only resolves when the asynchronous tasks have completed:
const aggregateSearch = async (term, AvailableApis) => {
    console.log("aggregateSearch");
    await Promise.all(AvailableApis.map((api) => {
        return fetchApi(api, term);  // <-- return the promise!
    }));
};

Finally, await the returned promises in your event handler:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {  // <-- make it async
    await loadCart(); // <-- await it
    await aggregateSearch("france", ["api1", "api2"]); // <-- await it
});

NB: that last await is not really needed, but it could become necessary when you decide to add more code in that event handler, which relies on the effects of agggregateSearch. So it is good practice to already put that await operator here.

Thx for your very detailed awser  I don’t especially wait for the loadCart to finish but I know this function is faster than aggregateSearch so it’s seems normal to expect that the cartCounter div should be updated first

"I know this function is faster": are you sure? It has to make 2 requests, while the search only makes 1 in your example.

I am did you check the jsfiddle into second post edit ?

When I run that fiddle, the output of "cart count done" comes last.

So to me that means that the time between the start of the event handler and the output of "cart count done" is longer than the time needed to produce the output "response from API done", which means that the asynchronous delay for loadCart takes more time than the asynchronous delay for aggregateSearch. How do you get to the conclusion that loadCard is faster than aggregateeSearch? I see the opposite...

that's the point it should comes before "response from API done" since fetchapi takes 2s and loadCart(100ms) + updateCartCount(100ms) takes 200ms

I don't see fetchapi taking 2 seconds when I run your fiddle. All finishes in much shorter delay. I honestly don't understand what the thing is that you want, except that I see some problems in your code that I have addressed in my answer.

Maybe the response gets cached, and that's why I don't see the delay. But either way, is the code change I suggest not doing what you need?

The proposals do give the expected result, but the problem I'm experiencing shouldn't happen. While waiting to find the reason, I'll add an await to the loadCart function. Many thanks for your help

Hopefully I understood the issue you're having.
I find that asynchronous functions may still interfere with each other when running on the same document -- especially when modifying elements. Although they're running at the same time, each line of code still takes a certain amount of time to execute (especially console.log()). They may be running at the same time, but they're also running on the same main thread more or less.
I ran into this issue when trying to implement loading symbols or progress bars. My loading symbols stuttered and my progress bars went from 0%-100% without any other steps.
The solution I found was Web Workers. Click here for a detailed guide for the Web Worker API.
Using a worker allows you to send logic to an entirely separate thread from the main thread -- freeing up the UI to be modified and interacted with without being interrupted.
Here is some code modified from what I use to create and run a simple Worker with code from the same file:


// The function to send to a Worker.
// NOTE that the code in this function won't be able to access variables outside of it or the document directly. That will have to be handled in the message event of our Worker.
function code(amount) {
 var values = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  values.push(Math.random());

  // Send our progress back to the main thread so we can show the user.
  postMessage([(i+1)/amount]);
 }

 // Send our final values.
 postMessage(values);
}

// Create a javaScript file as an Object URL.
var url = URL.createObjectURL(
 new Blob(
  // Place the code() function in the new JavaScript file.
  // Define the function for the Worker's onmessage event to start our function (doing this lets us send actual values and objects to the Worker and start it on demand).
  [`
   var code = ${code};
   onmessage = message => { postMessage(code(...message.data)); };
  `],
  {type: 'application/javascript'}
 )
);

// Create a worker with the script from our JavaScript file.
var customworker = new Worker(url);

// Add our Object URL to the customworker to access it later.
customworker.url = url;

// Add a function to revoke the Object URL when we terminate the worker.
customworker.resolve = function() {
 URL.revokeObjectURL(this.url);
 this.terminate();
};

var progress = document.querySelector('progress');

// Retrieve and process data whenever a message is posted using postMessage().
customworker.addEventListener('message', function(message) {
 if(message.data.length == 1) {
  // Show the user the progress of our function using the progress of the for loop in code().
  progress.value = message.data[0];
 } else {
  // Terminate the worker using our custom function since we know the worker is done.
  // If we want to use the code in the worker again and again, you don't need to do this.
  this.resolve();

  // Show the user what we want to show them of the result.
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = `1000000 random numbers were found. The final number was ${message.data.slice(-1)}.`;
 }
});

// Run the function in our Worker sending a parameter of 1000000 to code().
customworker.postMessage([1000000]);
<div>Running Worker...</div>
<progress max='1' value='0'/>



Here is a simplified version of the code above
function code() {
 // Your code here.
 // Use postMessage() to send data back to the document.
}
var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`var code = ${code}; onmessage = message => { postMessage(code(...message.data)); };`], {type: 'application/javascript'}));
var customworker = new Worker(url);
customworker.url = url;
customworker.resolve = function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(this.url); this.terminate(); };
customworker.addEventListener('message', function(message) {
 // Use message.data and manipulate the document here.
});
customworker.postMessage([/* Parameters go here. */]);

You could use a Worker in aggragateSearch() or fetchAPI() to offload the intense requirements of the fetch() function to a new thread, then you can update the div you hope to change in the Worker's 'message' eventListener.
For instance, your fetchApi function might look something like this (untested):
function fetchApi(api, term) {
 fetchApi.worker.postMessage([api, term]);
}
fetchApi.worker = new Worker(
 URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob(
   [`var code = ${
     (api, term) => fetch('aggregate.php', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({ source: api, term: term }) })
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => postMessage(result.formattedResponse))
    }; onmessage = message => { postMessage(code(...message.data)); };`],
   {type: 'application/javascript'}
  )
 )
);
fetchApi.worker.addEventListener('message', function(message) {
 document.getElementById('myDiv' + api).innerHTML = message.data;
});

If you can put your code in a real .js file, that might be cleaner than making a URL Object when using Workers.
This solution may not meet your need if I misunderstood your issue, -- and you would need to adapt it to your full code, -- but hopefully this is useful to you!

That an interesting way I’ll give it a try many thanks
